# Arranging data in arrays using PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

For some reason I having a hard time trying to arrange my data in arrays. Now I have a database that holds the title of a page, the content, id and date modified.

I have a function that calls onto another function that does a query and gets all the tables in that database table. Currently im just returning the titles of the pages because it's easy to do, but i'd like to use the id as well as the title. So I thought about using multidimensional arrays. I've used arrays in my life in different languages like C++, c#, java and so on, but got some reason the way PHP does it strikes me as odd, I think there is something im not getting.

So here i am looping through my records and putting the title in an array:

```
 while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    $pages[$count] = $row->title;
    $count++;
}

return $pages;
```

Would it be something like this:

```
$pages = array() 
{
    ["records"]=>
    array() 
    {
            [$count]=> $row->id
            [$count]=> $row->title
    }
}
```

Would this give me an output of something like this:

```
[0]=> 1, homePage
[1]=> 2, page2
[2]=> 3, anotherPage
```

Is this right? is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I gathered, you're trying to achieve this:

```
$pages = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    // Empty bracket syntax allows indices to be automatically incremented
    $pages[] = array("id" => $row->id, "title" => $row->title);
}
```

**Outputs**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => homePage
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => page2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => page3
        )

)
```

To access your page titles/IDs singularly:

```
echo $pages[2]['id'];    // 3
echo $pages[2]['title']; // page3
```

To loop through all of the elements in the array:

```
foreach ($pages AS $page) {
    echo $page['id'];
    echo $page['title'];
}
```

Comment: That is what im looing for. But one more thing, how do i output whats in the array? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I do this for my queries.  This allows you to not need to know what is coming back.  It does restrict by not only choosing what you want but I do that with my query if needed.

```
$strQuery = "your query";

$objResult = mysql_query( $strQuery );

$arrResults = array(  );

foreach ( $objResult->result_array(  ) as $arrRecord )
{
   $arrResults[] = $arrRecord;
}
```

Then anything that comes back through your query is stored in the `$arrResults` array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => title1
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => title2
    )

)
```